# How to grep for pipe |

Tags: grep, regular-expression, quoting, special-characters

How can I grep for line containing pipe character `|` or for character `>`:

```
files content:
|this is test
where is >
this is none
```

now what I need using grep command is

```
grep -iE "<some expression>" file_name
```

Output:

```
|this is test
where is >
```

Answer (score 13):

With standard `grep` syntax:

```
grep '[>|]'
```

or

```
grep -e '>' -e '|'
```

or

```
grep '>
|'
```

or

```
grep -E '>|\|'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using GNU grep you can do this with the *or* operator (`|`), which should be escaped (preceded by a backslash `\`). So to find lines containing either pipe or a greater-than sign, included them literally with the *or* operator:

```
grep '|\|>' infile
```

Output:

```
|this is test
where is >
```

Comment: `\|` is not a standard `BRE` operator, though it works with the GNU `grep` which is the `grep` found in most Operating systems built around a Linux kernel.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: thank you for pointing this out, I was not aware of it. I corrected the text.

Comment: Yes, the alternation operator is the only real addition of EREs over BREs, the rest (`+`, `?`) being syntactic sugar for `\{1,\}` and `\{0,1\}`. (on the other hand, EREs loose back references (`\(.\)\1`) which are a BRE only feature)

Answer (score 2):

Using bracket expression to match either of the wanted characters:

`grep "[|>]" infile`

Output:

```
|this is test
where is >
```

Comment: No need for either `-i` or `-E` here.

Comment: That's true, acknowledged.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to accomplish it is using -e flag which is specified by POSIX. E.g:

```
grep -e '>\||' infile
```

Comment: `grep -e '>' -e '|' infile` works too.

Comment: `-e` is specified by POSIX but is not useful here. `\|` is not specified by POSIX.